# Ни совсем корректная работа анимации при перелистывании вкладок (TabHost)

Tags: android-animation, android-linearlayout, android-tabs, scrollview

Здравствуйте,

хотел бы в свое приложение добавить анимацию при перелистовании пальцем вкладок. Т.е. примерно как страницы в книге.

Вкладки созданы с помощью **TabHost**. Т.к. в основном все вкладки длинные то в них я добавил **ScrollView**.

Активити со вкладками выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
         <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewTab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                   <-- Здесь все остальное содержимое вкладки1 -->
            </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>  

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewTab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

            LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                   <-- Здесь все остальное содержимое вкладки2 -->
            </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
        <-- И т.д. -->
```

Перелистование реализуется следующим образом.

Сперва ставим слушателя на касание экрана активити:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent) {



    switch (touchEvent.getAction()) {
        // when user first touches the screen to swap
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            mFirstTouchGestureX = touchEvent.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            float currentX = touchEvent.getX();

            // if left to right swipe on screen
            if (mFirstTouchGestureX > currentX) {

                switchTabs(false);
            }

            // if right to left swipe on screen
            if (mFirstTouchGestureX < currentX) {

                switchTabs(true);
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Далее реализуем непосредственно переключение вкладки и анимацию (чтобы не перегружать информацией приведу только код для перелистывания налево, т.е. старая(текущая) вкладка уходит левая вкладка приходит ) :

```
  public void switchTabs(boolean direction) {




    if (direction) // true = move left
    {
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {


            mLinearLayouts_Tabs[0].setAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
            mLinearLayouts_Tabs[tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount() - 1].
           setAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount() - 1);
        }
        else {



            mLinearLayouts_Tabs[ tabHost.getCurrentTab() ].
           setAnimation( outToRightAnimation() );
            mLinearLayouts_Tabs[ tabHost.getCurrentTab() - 1 ].
           setAnimation( inFromLeftAnimation() );

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabHost.getCurrentTab() - 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Параметры анимации описаны следующим образом (только для перелистывания на лево):

```
  public Animation outToRightAnimation(){
    Animation outToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outToLeft.setDuration(1000);
    outToLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outToLeft;

}

public Animation inFromLeftAnimation(){
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(1000);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}
```

При запуске приложения в идеале при перелистывании влево новая вкладка должна приходить слева, а старая(текущая) уходить направо .
 У меня же при перелистывании старой вкладки нет (т.е. она как бы исчезает во время перелистывания), а новая как положено приходит слева. Получается старая(текущая) вкладка при запуске анимации никуда не уходит, потому что ее нет (вместо нее пустая страница).

Причем происходит это когда во вкладке имеется **ScrollView** в виде родителя **LinearLayout**. Если **ScrollView** убрать перед **LinearLayout**, то все начинает работать нормально. Но от **ScrollView** я не могу отказаться, он нужен чтобы просматривать длинные вкладки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать так чтобы при наличии **ScrollView** над **LinearLayout** анимация работала правильно, т.е. при перелистывании влево, слева новая вкладка приходила, одновременно старая (текущая) уходила направо ?

Заранее спасибо большое всем за помощь.